# writing input/operation value in text file using bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I have some line in my bash script which computes value and displays in screen .Lets say,

```
Adder $a $b
```

I would like to print the value returned by Adder in text file.How would i do it?

Say adder runs for several loops .

Answer (score 1):

Try piping it to `tee`:

```
Adder $a $b | tee output.txt
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee

Comment: If you just want it in a file instead, `Adder $a $b > output.txt` will suffice. But `tee` is more general.